# Можно ли сохранить информацию в БД из консольного приложения на C/C++?

Tags: c, база-данных, c++

Добрый день.

Короче, задача такая: есть выборка информации, можно каждую запись вместо вывода на экран сохранить в БД? Без всяких форм, кнопочек и т. п. (консольное приложение).
На C/C++, база данных (MySQL).

Comment: @Pelmen1985, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Да.

Какая разница откуда сохранять и куда? Разве GUI отвечает за обработку запросов?

Comment: А можно пример? Хотя бы просто соединения под консолем?

Comment: Что значит пример?

Как пример и это можно зарулить: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-query.html

И это: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-sqlstatements.html

И еще 5 вариантов как минимум.

Пиши, что тебе нужно конкретнее.

Answer (score 3):

Правильный ответ: да, можно)